# Warning major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

Basicly I'm super newbie and started internship in IT company. I installed VS with Xamarin. The problem that I'm facing is very frustrating. So even when i create empty project I can't compile it and get error like this :

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Warning  major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.

I searched all over google and asked so many people and still no fix of my problem. If anybody can help me via skype or teamwiever i will APPRECIATE so much. My skype: toniterdal , feel free to add me.

Comment: This is a corrupt proguard.jar file watch the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41442038/3970581

Answer (score 63):

I was having the same issue, and tearing my hair out. I had the JDK Version 8 installed, but these warnings wouldn't go away, and eventually they generated a build-breaking error.

When I went to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin, and looked at the Android Settings, the Java Development Kit Location was pointing to jdk.1.7.xxxx, in `Program Files (x86)`.

I changed it to 1.8.0_101, in `Program Files`. Then I restarted Visual Studio, and the same error happened again. Somehow, Visual Studio was detecting Version 7 of the JDK and pointing it to that automatically.

So the solution turned out to be very simple. As well as installing Version 8 of the JDK, **UNINSTALL Version 7 of the JDK.** As soon as I did that, Xamarin turned out to be much better behaved. This step solved a whole bunch of seemingly unrelated problems.

[image]

Comment: This workd for me as well, but only after I also cleaned my solution.

Comment: Thanks - cleaning the solution also removed the "missing v7..." error.

Comment: Maybe obvious, but you may have to install the latest JDK from Oracle.

Answer (score 29):

That error is telling you that the Java Class version that is being loaded was compiled with Java 8 (52) but Java 7 (51) is trying to load that compiled class.

- Java 7 uses major version 51
- Java 8 uses major version 52

Check which Java version(s) are installed on your machine and review Xamarin's requirements and Java installation steps (linked below)

[Installing the Java SDK (JDK)](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_the_Java_SDK_JDK)

Answer (score 11):

For people having problems with setting the appropriate JDK version, you might want to try to override this setting in the vs2015 options dialog:

[image: Cross Platform Dialog]

Comment: worked great.. Save from big headache. can you share few lines about this answer (If possible)..

Comment: Actually I spend several hours "trail and error" various settings. When I stumbled upon this one, all seemed to work out but I haven't  done a in depth analysis. But it seems that the setting for the C++ cross platform settings interfere with the Xamarin ones

Answer (score 6):

Delete bin folder and obj folder and run the project it will be work fine

Answer (score 3):

You have a bad proguard.jar file, you need to replace this .jar by a correct version. The steps below describing how to do that.  Some colleagues had the same problem here.

- Go to Preferences => SDK locations  and copy the Android SDK location.
- Go to that folder (mostly /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx) and go to the folder tools/proguard/lib.
- Here you find a proguard.jar.
- Rename this to proguard_OLD.jar.
- Download the last proguard file (like this one https://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/files/)
- Unzip and place the proguard.jar in the tools/proguard/lib folder
- Rebuild your Project

Everything should be fixed!

You can find more info about the bug here:

- https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-android-sdk-build-tools-24/

Answer (score 2):

For me worked to change the SDK as well, but under Options->Xamarin->Android Settings, I don't have Cross Platform in Options for VS 2015Pro

Answer (score 2):

Note for Windows 64 bit users, the JDK has to be the x86 version not the x64 version.

E.g. C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111

Answer (score 1):

Kaloyan you can find the setting for the Java SKD under Tools->Options and the click on Xamarin in the Options list, then select Android Settings.  I installed the latest Java version (8.0.111) and then did a clean on my project and it runs fine now with no errors.  Thank you everyone for your posts!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i had to reinstall the JDK 8 (the last version) because other versions JDK 7 couldnt work even with new projects or clean up projects, and also i had to do a clean install of the android sdk.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the same issue I faced today:

From Control Panel > Uninstall a Program > uninstall the older Java versions which are on your system.
You should only have Jdk 1.8 and Jre 1.8 on your system.

Now go to C:/Program Files/Java and delete all older java versions.
If you have setup your JDK 1.8 and JRE 8 in C:/Program Files (x86)/Java then cut paste them into C:/Program Files/Java folder.

Then I restarted IntelliJ IDE which I am using. It automatically asked to update the path of SDK. Update the path to point to Jdk 1.8 and then I recompiled my files and things started working well.

Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had just deleted **.class** files and worked fine.