# How does one upgrade to Android SDK 25.1.3?

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

After the latest update to Xamarin, I get this error in design view

"The installed Android SDK is too old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is required."

Running the "Open Android SDK" and installing the latest version of Android Studio did not resolve the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't need to install Android Studio just to update the SDK. Matter of fact, Studio and the SDK versions are not related. Please show a screenshot of your SDK Manager showing you have the latest version

Comment: SDK manager did the trick, thanks Cricket

Comment: Could you please send more details about "the trick"? Updated Android SDK Tools to 25.2.2 did not help. Edit: http://imgur.com/a/GrWlo

Comment: Same issue than MortalFool. Any suggestion to resolve this?

Comment: It's October 2016, and on my laptop, Android SDK Manager only shows updates upto v24.4.1, but Xamarin (with VS2015) is demanding I get "v25.1.3 or newer", otherwise it can't even display the most basic of axml forms (the default one VS2015 creates, containing just one button !!).  Where can I find this elusive v25.x release of the SDK ?!

Comment: If you have issues finding/installing the Android SDK versions in VS2015, James from Xamarin seems to have the ultimate walkthrough:  http://motzcod.es/post/150380059392/preparing-machines-for-xamarin-cycle

Comment: Any movement on this? Xamarin's insane dependency spaghetti means that some NuGet package x relies on some NuGet package y, but you can't install y because some other package relies on it. It's driving me crazy! How do we just make sure we've got the latest NuGet packages?

Comment: I have the API 25 installed. I just can't grab the Xamarin NuGet packages.

Answer (score 11):

I got past this by installing SDK v23 (Android 6.0). When designer mode finally opened, even though I also have Android 7.0 installed, Android 6.0 was the only selectable "Version" at the top of designer mode. I have Visual Studio 2015 btw.

Comment: How Visual Studio 2015 have to do with Android development?

Comment: @Pongpat:  By using Xamarin.  It lets you write Android apps using VS2015  (assuming you can get past Xamarin's annoying demands for v24 or v25 of the Android SDK...)

Comment: You right! Thank you very much! It's shame for Xamarin to have an issues like these.

Comment: This worked for me. I installed Android 7.0, as well as version 25.1.3 specifically, but `Main.axml` only opened for me in a Blank application once I installed Android 6.0.

Comment: This answer fix my problem.

Answer (score 9):

So, I just figured this out and remembered this post, I've been struggling with this issue for hours now.

The problem seems to be that Xamarin doesn't recognize the latest SDK Tools (25.2.2) as a newer version than the minimum needed (25.1.3) so I tried downloading the SDK Tools with the same minor version as the needed one, closest I could find was 25.1.7 which you can get from the Google repository here:

- Windows:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.1.7-windows.zip
- Mac:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.1.7-macosx.zip
- Linux:
  https://dl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r25.1.7-linux.zip

Just extract the appropriate package for your platform into your SDK directory under tools and re-open Xamarin/Visual Studio and the Android designer should work again.

Answer (score 2):

To open the SDK Manager, click Tools > Android > SDK Manager or click SDK Manager  in the toolbar.

When an update is available for a package you already have, a dash  appears in the check box next to the package.

To update an item or install a new one, click the check box so it shows a checkmark.
To uninstall a package, click to clear the check box.
Pending updates are indicated in the left column with a download icon . Pending removals are indicated with a red cross .

To update the selected packages, click Apply or OK, then agree to any license agreements.

more details [Refer Here with image](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process that worked for me:

1. Install 64-bit JDK 1.8
2. Update Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and Build-tools. Close SDK
   Manager and repeat if the version required in the warning isn’t
   shown. You may need to exit Visual Studio if you get "Warning! A
   folder failed to be moved"
3. Make sure the Android settings in Visual Studio are pointing to the
   right locations: Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings

This is the full [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40154109/6146870) about what I did to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Iliya was almost there. My setup is: non-fresh VS2015E U3, Xamarin 4.2.0.695, Android SDK installer 24.4.1, Android NDK R13, JDK 7u71. Tried Iliya method (and much more), reinstall, move Android SDK, nothing helped.

Finally the solution was to **install all Android SDK Tools from API 14 (Android 4.0) up to the latest** using Android SDK manager. Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47251/the-installed-android-sdk-is-too-old-version-24-3-or-newer-is-required see **YuryShpakov** answer.

Though, there was more to do, at least for me: JDK 7 won't compile your blank Android app, you have to go for JDK 8, and also uninstall JDK 7, if you can afford. See **Rob's** resolve here: [Warning major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222584/warning-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-supported-b)

One more issue will likely come up, see this thread: [Error message "No exports were found that match the constraint contract name"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596543/error-message-no-exports-were-found-that-match-the-constraint-contract-name).

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help someone. Xamarin Studio has some weird file paths. Instead of checking files in Android SDK folder:
/Users//Library/Android/sdk
it checks them in
/Users//Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx

I installed latest platform and tools using Android SDK Manager, and them copied them to android-sdk-macosx folder myself. This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, my problem was solved after installing SDK Platform for Android 6.0 or API 23. Installing API 24 or higher i.e Android 7.x (Nougat) did not run. If still not solved then install SDK Platform for even lower APIs like 22,21 ...
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

After install android 6 (api 23) problem The "installed Android SDK is too old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is required." is Fixed.

- ndk version : android-ndk-r13b
- sdk version : API 25 & API 23 are installed
- jdk version : jdk1.8.0_112 64 bit
- xamarin version : 4.2.1.641