# Visual Studio 2015 - Android SDK version is too old

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I created a blank Android App and I get the following error when I try to view designer for Main.axml.

> [Something went wrong]
>
> The installed Android SDK is too old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is
>   required. Please update the latest version.

But I already have the latest version: Android SDK Tools 25.2.2

Please help me.

Comment: See my resolve here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40013941/6132885, hope this helps.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Ridiculous, isn't it ?  All I wanted to do was write my first Xamarin app, but I can't, due to this error.  Yet (on the same laptop) Android Studio runs perfectly.  I followed some StackOverflow tips to upgrade my Xamarin, and now it just demands an even higher version of the Android SDK !   I surrender....   I just wanted to write a dumb first Xamarin app, but can't even get that far.

Comment: Hi..... i solved this by installing the sdk build-tools from 19.1 up to 25.2.2. I also installed the API 25, 24 and 23. Some links mention the API 23 as the solution. I have followed this link: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/47251/the-installed-android-sdk-is-too-old-version-24-3-or-newer-is-required... good luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can’t open Xamarin Android .axml file: The installed Android SDK is too old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is required. Please update to the latest version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40154108/can-t-open-xamarin-android-axml-file-the-installed-android-sdk-is-too-old-ver)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the process that worked for me:

1. Install 64-bit JDK 1.8
2. Update Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and Build-tools. Close SDK
   Manager and repeat if the version required in the warning isn’t
   shown. You may need to exit Visual Studio if you get "Warning! A
   folder failed to be moved"
3. Make sure the Android settings in Visual Studio are pointing to the
   right locations: Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings

This is the full [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40154109/6146870) about what I did to resolve this issue.