# Xamarin Android Support v7 Errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-support-library

Im trying to make a toolbar with xamarin using android support v7 app combat. The thing is its working fine without support v7 app combat package but when i install the package i get like 60 errors all of a sudden. Some errors :

```
error:package android.support.v7.internal.widget does not exist

error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist
```

It is strange, i tried uninstalling the packages and re-installing them i also tried installing different versions of the packages. Both didnt work for me.

Edit: Screenshot

[image]

Comment: you have to install `android.suuport.design` and `android.support.v7.appCompat`. it will work..

Comment: I installed it. There are more errors now. Like android.support.design.widget.AppBarlayout does not exist

Comment: go to `User/username/AppData/Xamarin/Android.Support.*` and delete all the file..

Comment: I did and its still the same. I also re-installed all the packages after deleting the files.

Comment: The error is display in design Mode ?? or you rebuild your app then error is display..

Comment: When i open the project there are no errors. After i build the project the errors show up and stay there.

Comment: post the screenshot ??

Comment: Okay i editted my post. Uploaded the screenshot.

Comment: there is package problem in your case I think you are not clean `AppData/Local/Xamarin/Android`. data file. Otherwise you are not Install package clean way..visit this here you have get the idea : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/

Comment: I cleaned that folder there is nothing left related to android. Now it says  Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v4' available in SDK installer. Java library file 

C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.4.0.0\content\classes.jar doesn't exist.
15 errors like this

Comment: are you install Component using `Nuget` or Right Click on `Components/Get More Component` ??

Comment: Im installing components by using Nuget.

Comment: see here is same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437601/error-after-updating-the-android-support-library-v7-appcompat-to-the-21-0-3-vers

Comment: Okay now it throws another error.Major version 52 is newer than 51. My sdks are updated and xamarint android jdk path points jdk 1.8.

Comment: visit this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222584/warning-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-supported-b

Comment: Okay everything seems to work fine right now. If you answer the question i can mark it as an answer. Thanks dude.

Comment: did you get it Thank God..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to delete the Folder inside

`User/UserName/AppData/Local/Xamarin/Android.Support.v4/`

and then rebuild Again in `Visual Studio`. It will download again.

**Or** if you have this error

> Warning major version 52 is newer than 51

visit this below answer :

[Warning major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222584/warning-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-supported-b)