# xamarin Android App Error

Tags: android, visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I am starting with Xamarin with Visual Studio and created my simple first blank project but getting below error when adding an Android Layout

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: mono/android/AndroidDesignerHost : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

Comment: VS 2010 is not supported anymore.https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements Xamarin for Visual Studio supports any Visual Studio 2015 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise) and non-Express editions of Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222584/warning-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-supported-b)