# Unable to merge android manifest when build VR App to Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I got the following error when I try to build a VR App to android. I use Unity 5.4.1f1  and I already downloaded Java SE and SDK. I already installed Android 5.0.1 packages, but when I try to build and run on Unity, I got this error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests. See the Console for more details. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[

]
stdout[
Warning: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml:14, C:\Users\Peno\Desktop\testVR\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\gvr-permissionsupport-release\AndroidManifest.xml:3] Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion='22'> but library uses targetSdkVersion='24'
]
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandSafe (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of the error is:

```
Main manifest has <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion='22'> but library uses targetSdkVersion='24'
```

So check all your AndroidManifest files (commonly under Plugins/Android) for the line

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

change from 22 to 24

Note: If you are trying to build for DayDream VR you might need to download a different version of unity. Check https://unity3d.com/de/partners/google/daydream for further information.

Comment: Its not working for me. Getting these errors



`warning: D:\Software\sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar(java/lang/AutoCloseable.class): major version 52 is newer than 51, the highest major version supported by this compiler.
  It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.`

Comment: That's a completely unrelated error. However, if you enter "major version 52 is newer than 51" in the search box in the upper right corner you will find answers: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222584/warning-major-version-52-is-newer-than-51-the-highest-major-version-supported-b